# python requests File Upload

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь загрузить файл на сайт.
Выдает ошибку:

> No file was uploaded

---

```
import requests

import requests

url =  "https://waifu2x.booru.pics/Home/upload"

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

data= {
"Content-Disposition: form-data"
"name":"img",
"filename":"1.jpg"
"Content-Type: image/jpeg"
"ÿØÿà"

         }


files = {'upload_file': open('1.jpg','rb')}


r = requests.post(url,headers=headers, files=files, data=data)
```

Comment: 1) `No file was uploaded` нифига не понятно, дайте полную трассу с ошибкой. 2) А "ÿØÿà" это что такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил поразбираться и найти ошибку, и [в итоге сделал готовое решение](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/9742d39bc95407f664429fb4a44dc87ac3049ab7/requests__examples/upload_image_to_waifu2x_booru_pics/main.py).

Алгоритм:

- Нужно отправить файл с специальным названием `img` и параметры `denoise` и `scale`
- Сайт перенаправит на страницу обработки, поэтому желательно дождаться обработки
- Когда обработка завершится сайт отправит на страницу с загруженной картинкой

Код:

```
import time
import requests

URL = "https://waifu2x.booru.pics/Home/upload"
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65",
}
DATA = {
    'denoise': '1',
    'scale': '1',
}
FILES = {
    'img': open('image.jpg', 'rb')
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(HEADERS)

    rs = s.post(URL, files=FILES, data=DATA)

    # Ждем пока файл обработается на сервере
    while '/Home/status?' in rs.url:
        rs = s.get(rs.url)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    print(rs.url)
```

---

**PS.**

Заметил интересное, если приглядеться, то URL к картинкам имеет хеш, например c8a984fc10b416869ca04c8f8629d429d4b28461. Проверил и этот хеш является SHA1

Comment: Спасибо за решение проблемы но я так и не понял откуда вы узнали эти данные. 'denoise': '1',
    'scale': '1' Сильно не пинайте только учусь.

Comment: @АнтонГорбунов, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). А я посмотрел в инспекторе браузера что тот отправлял. И еще на самой форме `<form>` должны были указаны эти параметры в <input>. PS. вопросы это нормально, поэтому не стесняйтесь их задавать :)